# Process search keywords with logical options

Tags: ruby, string

I want to processes a string of search keywords with options `"and"`, `"or"`, and `"not"`, such as `"gis and gjs not gkp"` in order to perform search with each keyword, and record the search logic.

To do so, I need to break up the search string by `"and"`, `"or"`, and `"not"`, and remember which divider was used at each point. I want to transform it to maybe a hash: `{and: 'gis', and: 'gjs', not: 'gkp'}`.

What's the best way to do this? Or is there a better way to process such a search string?

Comment: key `:and` is duplicated and will be overwritten.

Comment: You are right.. so I'll have to make and: point to an array instead I guess. Zooming out, is this even the correct idea to process search string?

Comment: Do you need an ad-hoc solution or a correct one? The latter would involve building a grammar parser. The former might be done with plain old good regexps.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with Boolean. You just have conjunction, disjunction, and negation, but you are not doing any Boolean algebra.

Comment: Hi sawa, in theory the logic could get more complex, such as `(a or d) not (b or c)` - is this what you mean by Boolean algebra? If there is any existing methods/module to process this that'll be great. I write the string in a simple way coz I myself can only realistically handle the easy use cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
splitted = "hello and world or jump not read".split(/( and | or | not )/)
# => ["hello", " and ", "world", " or ", "jump", " not ", "read"]

splitted = splitted.unshift('and') unless splitted[0] == 'and'
# => ["and". "hello", " and ", "world", " or ", "jump", " not ", "read"]

splitted.each_slice(2).to_h
# => {"and"=>"hello", " and "=>"world", " or "=>"jump", " not "=>"read"}
```

Comment: This is a great idea! a couple of minor points: a. prepend! is not a valid method - I need to use unshift instead (maybe I'm using an older version of ruby?); b. each_slice(2).to_a seems to be easier to break up the array; c. as Sagar pointed out, if there are multiple or/not/and, some keyword will be overwritten. Still, your way is better than what I'm working with. I just need to work on the downstream processing a bit. Thank you!